# Visualize manifold specified by equalities

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have two nonlinear equalities $x^3 = y^2, y = z^3$. How can I visualize the manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is generated by simultaneously satisfying the two equalities? I think `ContourPlot3D` is the one to use but I couldn't get it to work show the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that satisfy the two equalities. The best I can do is make it show the intersection of the surfaces:

[image]

How can I plot the curve defined by the intersection in 3D?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the option `BoundaryStyle` to mark the intersection of the two contour surfaces as follows:

```
ContourPlot3D[{x^3 == y^2, y == z^3}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Opacity[.3], 
 BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> Directive[Thick, Red]}]
```

[image]

Also

```
SliceContourPlot3D[y - z^3,  x^3 == y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 Contours -> {{0}}, BoundaryStyle -> None, ContourShading -> None, 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I follow most of it: Since a list was passed as first argument the '{1 -> None, 2-> None ... }' but how Mathematica knew to handle {1,2} -> is just magic!

Answer (score 4):

```
r = 1;
R = ImplicitRegion[{x^3 == y^2, y == z^3}, {{x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r}}];
Region[R]
```